# When did the Joyal model structure on simplicial sets originate?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories

Some of the earliest writings on the [Joyal model structure on simplicial sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+for+quasi-categories) include Jacob Lurie's account in [Higher Topos Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608040v1) from 2006,
as well as Joyal's own account in [The Theory of Quasi-Categories and its Applications](https://mat.uab.cat/%7Ekock/crm/hocat/advanced-course/Quadern45-2.pdf) from 2008.

I have seen unsourced claims that this model structure may originate in 1980s, possibly in the correspondence between Joyal and Grothendieck.  However, an examination of the only available [letter from Joyal to Grothendieck](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Egeorges.maltsiniotis/ps/lettreJoyal.pdf) does not reveal any material on quasicategories.  I was unable to find any other correspondence between Joyal and Grothendieck.

In his 2008 notes cited above, Joyal says “The results presented here are the fruits of a long term research project which began around thirty years ago.”, which appears to indirectly corroborate the above unsourced claims.

**When did the Joyal model structure on simplicial sets originate?  Is there any written source that confirms its existence in 1980s?**

Comment: Is there some reason for not asking Joyal about this?

Comment: @AndrejBauer the categories mailing list is the obvious place to ask, but I found it quicker to try to reconstruct upper and lower bounds from the available literature

Comment: Sending an email to Joyal is even obviouser.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: One reason is to see whether I missed something, before I start bothering him with questions.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: About "unsourced claims that this model structure may originate ... in the correspondence between Joyal and Grothendieck", perhaps this is a confusion with the "Joyal-Jardine model structure" on sheaves of simplicial sets, which I believe had its origin in exactly this way.

Comment: @CharlesRezk yes, that was my mistake here on MO long ago, which was the source for the nLab claim about the Joyal model structure on sSet.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov did you end up emailing Joyal?

Comment: @DavidRoberts: See my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is what André Joyal wrote in an email to me:

> No, I have not discovered the model structure for quasi-categories in the 1980's.
> I became interested in quasi-categories (without the name) around 1980
> after attending a talk by Jon Beck on the work of Boardman and Vogt.
> I wondered if category theory could be extended to quasi-categories.
> In my mind, a crucial test was to show that a quasi-category is a Kan complex
> if its homotopy category is a groupoid.
> All my attempts at showing this have failed for about 15 years, until I stopped trying hard!
> I found a proof after extending to quasi-categories a few basic notions of category theory.
> This was around 1995. The model structure for quasi-categories was discovered soon after.
> I did not publish it immediately because I wanted to show that it could
> be used for proving something new in homotopy theory.
> I am a bit of a perfectionist (and overly ambitious?).
> I was  hoping to develop a synthesis between category theory and homotopy theory
> (hence the name quasi-categories).
> I met Lurie at a conference organised by Carlos Simpson in Nice (in 2001?).
> I gave a talk on the model structure and Lurie asked for a copy of my notes afterward.
> I intuitively understood that he could develop the
> theory of quasi-categories more and better than I could.
> He was young and a better mathematician than I was.
> I do not regret it.

Answer (score 14):

My suspicion is now that it was some time between 2004 and 2006. I have a lot more citations in [this blog post](https://thehighergeometer.wordpress.com/2022/06/20/when-was-the-joyal-model-structure-on-sset-born/), but I note three points, in reverse chronological order:

1. Multiple experts are referring to the Joyal model structure in mid-2006, in print (Joyal–Tierney, Verity, Lurie,...).
2. At the June 2004 IMA conference, the joint Joyal–May–Porter presentation on models for weak higher categories, including quasi-categories, made no mention on [the slides](https://web.archive.org/web/20050308200007/http://www.ima.umn.edu/talks/workshops/SP6.7-18.04/may/PorterMay.pdf) of the model structure. Further, [Tim Porter's own 2004 notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20050308202711/http://www.ima.umn.edu/talks/workshops/SP6.7-18.04/porter/s-catsv2.pdf) linked to that talk call the question of the relation between quasi-categories and Segal categories a "vague" one. This question was answered by [Joyal and Tierney in 2006](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607820) giving the Quillen equivalence of model structures.
3. There is no mention of a model structure in Joyal's [2002 paper on quasi-categories and Kan complexes](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049%2802%2900135-4).