# Cohomology without comonad?

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, higher-category-theory, universal-algebra, monads

**TL;DR.** Many cohomologies can be unified using comonads. Question: which cohomologies cannot be?

---

For each algebraic theory, there is an adjunction, and therefore a (co)monad (or called a (co)triple). A comonad is a special comonoid, so by a universal property of $\Delta^{op}$ we get a cosimplicial object (the Bar construction [1]).

From this, one derives a cohomology theory of this algebraic theory. **This subsumes group cohomology, Lie algebra cohomology, Hochschild cohomology**, and Harrison's cohomology for commutative algebras [2, chapter 6+7].

#### Question

1. What cohomology theories are known to not from comonads?
2. Thinking of a group as a category with one object, this line of thoughts fits naturally into. Does it has an analogy to higher categories too?

#### Reference

- [1] https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-spring2007/qg-spring2007.html#computation
- [2] Acyclic Models-[Michael Barr]

Comment: How about singular cohomology?

Comment: I don't know much really.. isn't it a comonad cohomology in some way?

Comment: [Godement resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godement_resolution) for computing sheaf cohomology can be viewed as coming from a particular adjunction, hence from a comonad. To give an example of some cohomology *not* coming from a comonad you have to come up with meaningful right derived functors of a functor which does not have an adjoint. There must be such examples except I cannot think of any right now

Comment: It seems by the adjunction functor theorem, many meaningful functors are adjoints naturally. Leave alone cohomologies! This is non-rigorous I know. I mentioned it just to strengthen my doubt.

Comment: Well, how about K-theory then?